# Why won't the portal keys drop when destroying links?

Tags: ingress

I have seen this multiple times where I have destroyed a portal and its links yet keys do not drop at either the portal I destroyed nor the other portal it was linked to. What is funny is that it seems to only happen to the portals/links of these one or two specific players. Anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the key is being picked up by a random passerby.

Answer (score 9):

A few things to note:

1. Key drops on link destruction is **based on a chance**, it is **not** a **guaranteed** drop (Much like the chance when hacking a Portal).
2. **If** a key drops, it could drop at either one of the Portals, also based on a chance.
3. The Owner of the Portal, the amount or levels of its Resonators and the Mods on said Portal does not have an influence on any of these two chances.

Comment: The second item isn't true. Keys drop on either side of the link. Its point is based on a chance calculation, too.

Comment: Actually the key drop is by chance but WHICH key drops depends on which key was used to make the link.  If the link was made from A to B then there is a chance that the key for B will drop at portal A.  There is NO chance that a key for A would drop at portal B.  Whichever key was used to create the link is the one that will drop.

Answer (score 6):

Key drop on link destruction isn't guaranteed. It's entirely possible to destroy a big number of links without receiving any related key, the same way a key drop isn't guaranteed when hacking a portal.

It has absolutely no relationship with the owner of the portal, it's just a matter of chance.